# Tracking while reading a text file in Java

Tags: java, input, output, bufferedreader

I'm trying to build a program with BufferedReader that reads a file and keeps track of vowels, words, and can calculate avg # of words per line. I have the skeleton in place to read the file, but I really don't know where to take it from here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaReader
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String line;
        BufferedReader in;

        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("message.txt"));

        line = in.readLine();

        while(line != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = in.readLine();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Please use Java naming conventions. Classes should be in `PascalCase`. As you have just started I recommend you rename your class before you have lots of classes with the problem.

Comment: To keep track of the amount of words per line, you could split each line by whitespaces (and punctuation marks) to get an array containing all words. Then you simply get the size of this array, to know the acutal word amount.

Comment: Using scanner tokens or a string tokeniser is a far easier way of accomplishing that.

Comment: @NicRobertson care to post an example? Im fairly new to Java.

Comment: @Zack I already did look down a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got. The word counting is questionable, but works for an example that I will give. Changes can be made (I accept criticism).

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaReader
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("message.txt"));
        String line = in.readLine();

        // for keeping track of the file content
        StringBuffer fileText = new StringBuffer();

        while(line != null) {
            fileText.append(line + "\n");
            line = in.readLine();
        }

        // put file content to a string, display it for a test
        String fileContent = fileText.toString();
        System.out.println(fileContent + "--------------------------------");

        int vowelCount = 0, lineCount = 0;

        // for every char in the file
        for (char ch : fileContent.toCharArray())
        {
            // if this char is a vowel
            if ("aeiou".indexOf(ch) > -1) {
                vowelCount++;
            }
            // if this char is a new line
            if (ch == '\n') {
                lineCount++;
            }
        }
        double wordCount = checkWordCount(fileContent);
        double avgWordCountPerLine = wordCount / lineCount;

        System.out.println("Vowel count: " + vowelCount);
        System.out.println("Line count: " + lineCount);
        System.out.println("Word count: " + wordCount);
        System.out.print("Average word count per line: "+avgWordCountPerLine);
    }

    public static int checkWordCount(String fileContent) {

        // split words by puncutation and whitespace
        String words[] = fileContent.split("[\\n .,;:&?]"); // array of words
        String punctutations = ".,:;";
        boolean isPunctuation = false;
        int wordCount = 0;

        // for every word in the word array
        for (String word : words) {

            // only check if it's a word if the word isn't whitespace
            if (!word.trim().isEmpty()) {
                // for every punctuation
                for (char punctuation : punctutations.toCharArray()) {

                    // if the trimmed word is just a punctuation
                    if (word.trim().equals(String.valueOf(punctuation)))
                    {
                        isPunctuation = true;
                    }
                }

                // only add one to wordCount if the word wasn't punctuation
                if (!isPunctuation) {
                    wordCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        return wordCount;
    }
}
```

---

Sample input/output:

File:

```
This is a test. How do you do?


This is still a test.Let's go,,count.
```

Output:

```
This is a test. How do you do?


This is still a test.Let's go,,count.
--------------------------------
Vowel count: 18
Line count: 4
Word count: 16
Average word count per line: 4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Scanner to pass over the the line and retrieve every token of the string line.

```
line = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""); //remove all punctuation
line = line.toLowerCase();               //make line lower case
Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
String word = scan.next();
```

Then you could loop through each token to calculate the vowels in each word.

```
for(int i = 0; i < word.legnth(); i++){
    //get char
    char c = word.charAt(i);
    //check if the char is a vowel here
    if("aeiou".indexOf(c) > -1){
        //c is vowel
    }
}
```

All you need to do is set a couple of counter ints to keep track of these and you're laughing.

Ahh, if you want to make sure that there are no non-words such as " - " counting as a word, the easiest way would probably be to strip all non-alphanumeric characters out of the text.
I also added it above.

```
 line = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
 line = line.toLowerCase();
```

Oh and since you are new to java don't forget to import

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: By default a `Scanner` tokenises on whitespace - so that hypen there would be a word. The OP probably doesn't want that.

Comment: A couple of trims, some regex and some #contains would solve that imo.

Comment: `if("aeiou".indexOf(c) < 0){` needs a fix